# The type 'Component' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, aws-lambda, visual-studio-2017

I am using .NET Core 1.0 Framework to connect to a MySql database. Since the references does not have MySQL.data dll I added it to the project, but it is throwing the error for System.Data. I added the reference for system.dll as well, and since There is no `project.json` in this template, I added the reference manually in `.csproj` file.

[image]

But when I am building the project it is still throwing an error.

[image]

Comment: Use the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/7.0.7-m61 it is prerelease and works with .net core

Comment: It worked Thank you. :)

Comment: But what about other references how to add references for for .netframework 4.6.2 to .netcore 1.0

Comment: Made the pictures visible, and modified a few issues with the wording to make it easier to understand and read.